# Converting color to equivalent with opacity

Tags: color

Assume a color X with alpha 1 and RGB 255,230,210.

How can i find another color with alpha A ( or an array of colors ) that blended with a background of color Y ( e.g 255,255,255 ) would produce the original color  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what function you're blending with. Since you don't say where you're doing this, I'll just take OpenGL as an example.

As you can see in the [API](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml), there are several ways of blending two colours (or rather how to interpret these two colours for a given blend function).

You speak of a colour and a background colour, so let's say your result is $c_r$, your object in the foreground has colour $c_s$ (for Source, the new colour value being "added" someway) and your background has colour $c_d$ (for Destination, the old colour value that has been in the buffer already).

Let $c_s = \left(\begin{array}{c} R_s\\G_s\\B_s\\A_s \end{array}\right)$ (and analogously for $c_r$ and $c_d$).

> To determine the blended RGBA values of a pixel, the system uses the following equations:
> $R_d = min(k_{R'}, R_s s_R + R_d d_R) \ G_d = min(k_{G'}, G_s S_G + G_d d_G) \ B_d = min(k_{B'}, B_s s_B + B_d d_B) A_d = min(k_{A'}, A_s s_A + A_d d_A)$

A bit confusing with the doubled $R_d$ and so forth, so I'll rewrite it to the denomination I defined earlier:

$R_r = min(k_{R'}, R_s s_R + R_d d_R) \ G_r = min(k_{G'}, G_s S_G + G_d d_G) \ B_r = min(k_{B'}, B_s s_B + B_d d_B) A_r = min(k_{A'}, A_s s_A + A_d d_A)$

The min function is there for not going above a certain constant (and $k_{R'},\ k_{G'},\ k_{B'},\ k_{A'}$ are simply constants). For our purposes, let's just assume that we don't surpass this threshold, so we end up with

$R_r = R_s s_R + R_d d_R$ (and of course the same for the other channels).

The rest of the components $s_R$ and $d_R$ which are some scaling factors for combining the two colours.

> Transparency is best implemented using blend function (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) with primitives sorted from farthest to nearest.

This helps, because now we know what the factors $s_R$ and $d_R$ actually are: the alpha values of the **Source**.

This leaves us with

$R_r = R_s A_s + (1 - R_d A_d)$

Therefore, to come back to your example, we have (for the green channel, since that is not $255$):

$G_r = 230$, an undefined $\alpha$ value for the source, the background green $G_d = 255$ and probably a solid background, meaning $A_d = 255$. We need the values to be in $\left[0, 1\right]$, therefore we get $G_r = \frac{230}{255} = 0.90196078431$, $G_d = 1$ and $A_d = 1$.

Filling this in we get:

$0.90196078431 = G_s A_s + (1 - 1 \cdot A_s)$

Your question lets me believe, that you know $A_s$, thus only $G_s$ (and of course the same for the other colour channels) is missing. This can then be calculated by isolating the respective colour component.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that for some alphas and colour combinations, the colours may come out of the equation negative e.g. if you want to turn a pure red background into pure green, there's only a positive solution if $\alpha = 1$